# Помогите решить логическое выражение

Tags: булева-алгебра

Есть такое выражение

```
(a+b)(b'+a)(c'+b) = ? = ab + ac' = a(b+c')
```

можете ли объяснить промежуточные шаги которые нужно выполнить чтобы получить такой результат?
законы логических операций знаю только в теории, на практике мало сталкивался

Comment: Самое простое - попробовать раскрыть все скобки, и посмотреть что получится.

Comment: А что значит `'` ? Ну и вообще что означают эти операции?

Comment: @insolor `a +b ba c + b` так правильно?

Comment: @Alexey Ten ' это отрицание

Comment: @Александр без понятия. У меня вообще abc' в конце получается, но не гарантирую что все правильно раскрыл. Можно по таблице истинности проверить, но сейчас на это времени нет.

Comment: @insolor т.е. вы не знаете как решать?

Comment: @Александр т.е. я теоретически предполагаю, что можно скобки раскрывать по правилам арифметики, но не уверен, что правильно правила применил и нигде не ошибся. Для гарантии нужно проверять что у первоначального выражения такая же таблица истинности, как у конечного.

Comment: a + b b a' c + b' или так может?

Comment: Стройте таблицу истинности и проверяйте, что вы меня спрашиваете правильно или не правильно вы сделали. Я не учитель, правильный ответ на бумажке у меня не записан.

Comment: Меня смущает последняя скобка (`(c'b)`). Там точно `+` не пропущен?

Comment: @Alexey Ten кстати да, вчера два вопроса задал здесь и в них допустил ошибки по невнимательности. просто ещё не привык к этим логическим знакам +'.

Comment: `(a+b)(b'+a)(c' + b)` поправил

Comment: @Alexey Ten можете подсказать почему закрыли тему?

Answer (score 1):

Давайте постепенно раскроем скобки в данном логическом выражении:

```
(a+b)(b'+a)(c'+b) = (a+b)(b'+a)c' + (a+b)(b'+a)b
```

Теперь мы можем применить закон дистрибутивности:

```
= (a(b'+a)c' + b(b'+a)c') + (a(b'+a)b + b(b'+a)b')

= ac' + bc' + ab + ab'

= ab + ac'
```

Таким образом, данное логическое выражение эквивалентно `ab + ac'`, что можно переписать как `a(b+c')`.

Ответ на комментарий Александра:

> с дистрибутивностью более менее понятно. объясните ещё пожалуйста как
> из этого ac' + bc' + ab + ab' получилось это ab + ac'?

Из выражения `ac' + bc' + ab + ab'` можно вынести общий множитель a и получить:

```
   ac' + bc' + ab + ab' = a(c' + b) + ab'
```

Теперь мы можем применить закон дистрибутивности и получить:

```
   a(c' + b) + ab' = ac' + ab + ab'
```

Замечу, что `ab + ab' = a(b + b') = a`, так как `b + b' = 1` (так как b' есть отрицание b). Тогда:

```
   ac' + ab + ab' = ac' + a = a(c' + 1) = a
```

Таким образом, `ac' + bc' + ab + ab' = ab + ac'`.

Comment: с дистрибутивностью более менее понятно. объясните ещё пожалуйста как из этого `ac' + bc' + ab + ab'` получилось это `ab + ac'`?

Comment: @Александр Ответ на ваш вопрос внес в свой ответ.

Comment: за что тут минус отвечающему? Оставьте комментарий минусующие, а то уже никуда не годится

Comment: @Dmitry, отвечающий неверно раскрывает скобки ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy Надо же указать не ошибку... все мы ошибаемся,  можно ведь и не заметить же

Comment: @Vladimir Glinskikh подскажите, я так понимаю это выражение `ac' + bc' + ab + ab'` и это `ab + ac'` должно иметь одинаковую таблицу истинности. а почему это не так? Или если это выражение сократить `(a(b'+a)c' + b(b'+a)c') + (a(b'+a)b + b(b'+a)b')` и получить `ac' + bc' + ab + bb'` всё равно не сходится таблица